# Select Oracle retornando inúmeras vezes o mesmo resultado

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-select

O meu select funciona e retorna o dado que preciso, porém ele esta retornando mais de 6000 vezes o mesmo resultado.

Como faço para ele retornar o resultado em apenas 01 linha.

OBS.: Só existe um unico resultado para este código `sq_transação`, não existe a possibilidade de duplicidade ou outros registros com o mesmo código, o que a querie esta fazendo é mostrar inumeras vezes o mesmo resultado.

```
Select  T.Cd_Fase, F.ds_Fase, T.Nu_Msisdn, p.cd_tecnologia,T.Nu_Iccid Simcard, Sq_Transacao, To_char(Dh_Entrada, 'DD/MM/YY, HH24:MI:SS') Data, T.Cd_Erro_Api 
  from transacao t, Fase_Processamento F, plano p
  where F.Cd_Fase = T.Cd_Fase --and Nu/Msisdn In ('');
  and sq_transacao = '12590061';
```

Comment: tenta colocar um DISTINCT depois do Select para ver se resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o amigo Joel Rodrigues falou

> Como você está fazendo o select sobre várias tabelas, o resultado final é um cruzamento dos registros. Utilize ao invés disso um inner join para relacionar as tabelas.

Faz assim para ficar mas legivel.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SQ_TRANSACAO,
       T.CD_FASE,
       F.DS_FASE,
       T.NU_MSISDN,
       TEC.DS_TECNOLOGIA,
       C.NO_CLIENTE,
       C.NU_CPF,
       T.NU_ICCID SIMCARD,
       TO_CHAR(DH_ENTRADA, 'DD/MM/YY, HH24:MI:SS') DATA,
       T.CD_ERRO_API 
FROM TRANSACAO T,
INNER JOIN FASE_PROCESSAMENTO F ON F.CD_FASE = T.CD_FASE
INNER JOIN PLANO P ON O.SQ_PLANO = T.SQ_PLANO
INNER JOIN TECNOLOGIA TEC ON TEC.CD_TECNOLOGIA ON P.CD_TECNOLOGIA
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.SQ_CLIENTE = T.SQ_CLIENTE
WHERE SQ_TRANSACAO IN ('12590061','12590062', '12590063');
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Como você está fazendo o select sobre várias tabelas, o resultado final é um cruzamento dos registros.
Utilize ao invés disso um inner join para relacionar as tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi utilizando um `distinct` e melhorando o relacionamento nas tabelas.

```
Select distinct  Sq_Transacao,T.Cd_Fase, F.ds_Fase, T.Nu_Msisdn, tec.ds_tecnologia, c.no_cliente, c.nu_cpf, T.Nu_Iccid Simcard, To_char(Dh_Entrada, 'DD/MM/YY, HH24:MI:SS') Data, T.Cd_Erro_Api 
  from transacao t, Fase_Processamento F, plano p, tecnologia tec, cliente c
  where F.Cd_Fase = T.Cd_Fase 
  and p.sq_plano = t.sq_plano 
  and p.cd_tecnologia = tec.cd_tecnologia
  and c.sq_cliente = t.sq_cliente
  and sq_transacao in ('12590061','12590062', '12590063');
```